# How Can I change the machine name of product type

Tags: commerce

How can I change the machine name of product type (in drupal commerce ) after it created and has several content , as example I has `tv` porduct type I want to change it to `LCDTV` , How can I change it?

Answer (score 2):

You can alter the machine name through the database to change the product type. See table `commerce_product_type` and alter the 'type' column.

Make proper adjustments in `commerce_product` for products using the old type. You could execute something like the following SQL query

```
UPDATE commerce_product SET type = REPLACE(type, "tv", "lcdtv");
```

Be sure to test this on a local or development version of the site.

UPDATE: As mentioned by Clive, you also have to update field data/revision tables.

You'd want to run `UPDATE field_table_name SET bundle = REPLACE(bundle, "tv", "lcdtv");` on any field_data_* or field_revision_* table that relates to your product type.

Comment: and thoroughly clear all caches related, of course.

Comment: It really isn't that simple - you'll also need to update the bundle in all field data/revision tables, for example

Comment: @Clive is correct. You'd also have to update related `field_data_*` and `field_revision_*` tables. Answer updated appropriately.