# How can I convert a set of Products to another Product Type?

Tags: commerce

We've decided to set up another Product Type and would like to convert some of the Products to another Type.

Is there a reliable way to convert a set of Products to another Product Type?

I saw this question which seems related, but it seems kind of 'hackish': [How Can I change the machine name of product type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/110465/how-can-i-change-the-machine-name-of-product-type)

Is there a tool or procedure which is known to work reliably?

Comment: Did you ever find a clean solution to the problem that was a tool for doing this?